# R Shiny Dashboard - Freq function cannot be sort by descending order

Tags: r, shiny

I am experiencing a tech issue by using R Shiny Dashboard, the freq function has some restriction.

Does anyone know how to select out the top 10 records by a descending order?

Question 1: sort parameter in freq function not working.
Question 2: cannot select out the top 10 rankings.

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  dt <- reactiveVal()

  # Freq Count #
  observeEvent(input$upload,{
    file <- input$file
    if (is.null(file)){
      return(NULL)
    }else if(endsWith(file$name, '.sas7bdat')){
      dat <- data.frame(setDT(read_sas(file$datapath)))
      freq <- freq(dat$VAR1, ord="desc")
    }
    dt(freq)
    
    output$preview <- renderDataTable(
      freq()
    )
})
```

The error message I got was as below.

```
Warning in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) :
  "ord" is not a graphical parameter
Warning in axis(if (horiz) 2 else 1, at = at.l, labels = names.arg, lty = axis.lty,  :
  "ord" is not a graphical parameter
Warning in title(main = main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...) :
  "ord" is not a graphical parameter
Warning in axis(if (horiz) 1 else 2, cex.axis = cex.axis, ...) :
  "ord" is not a graphical parameter
```

Comment: @akrun library(summarytools), thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `freq` from `summarytools` there is no argument named `ord`, but there is an `order`.  According to the `?freq` documentation, there is only three values it can take and 'desc' is not among them

> order - Ordering of rows in frequency table; “name” (default for non-factors), “level” (default for factors), or “freq” (from most frequent to less frequent). To invert the order, place a minus sign before or after the word. “-freq” will thus display the items starting from the lowest in frequency to the highest, and so forth.

Based on that, if we need to sort in descending, it would be

```
freq(dat$VAR1, order ="freq")
```

and the one for ascending will be `"-freq"`

---

Using a small reproducible example

```
library(summarytools)
set.seed(24)
dat <- data.frame(VAR1 = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE))
```

-in descending

```
freq(dat$VAR1, order = 'freq')
Frequencies  
dat$VAR1  
Type: Character  

              Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.
----------- ------ --------- -------------- --------- --------------
          b     24     24.00          24.00     24.00          24.00
          c     22     22.00          46.00     22.00          46.00
          a     19     19.00          65.00     19.00          65.00
          e     19     19.00          84.00     19.00          84.00
          d     16     16.00         100.00     16.00         100.00
       <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
      Total    100    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
```

-in ascending

```
freq(dat$VAR1, order = '-freq')
Frequencies  
dat$VAR1  
Type: Character  

              Freq   % Valid   % Valid Cum.   % Total   % Total Cum.
----------- ------ --------- -------------- --------- --------------
          d     16     16.00          16.00     16.00          16.00
          a     19     19.00          35.00     19.00          35.00
          e     19     19.00          54.00     19.00          54.00
          c     22     22.00          76.00     22.00          76.00
          b     24     24.00         100.00     24.00         100.00
       <NA>      0                               0.00         100.00
      Total    100    100.00         100.00    100.00         100.00
```

---

Regarding the OP's question

> Does anyone know how to select out the top 10 records by a descending order?`

The code is not reproducible, but it seems that the OP used a wrong function to do the task.  Here, we could use `arrange` or `slice_max` by specifying the `n` as 10 and the `order_by` variable as the count created

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    add_count(VAR1) %>%
    arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
    filter(VAR1 %in% head(unique(VAR1), 3))
```

Or if we need a summarised output

```
dat %>% 
    count(VAR1) %>% 
    slice_max(n = 3, order_by = n)
```

Comment: could you pls check my error message in the post 'Warning in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log = log, ...) :
  "ord" is not a graphical parameter'

Comment: @qifengwu it is not a reproducible post

Comment: To keep only the 10 most frequent, you can use freq's _rows_ argument. In this example, to keep 4 most frequent: `freq(dat$VAR1, order = '-freq', rows = 1:4)`